# IndexedBD: выбрать записи от большего к меньшему

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как выбрать записи не от меньшего к большему, а от большего значения к меньшему.

```
//Выбираем предположим объекты со свойством от 0 -> 2, а как от 2 -> 0?
function getDataByRange(db, table, index, lower, upper, fun){

    var data = [];
    var tx = db.transaction(table, "readonly");
    var store = tx.objectStore(table);
    var index = store.index(index);

    var boundKeyRange = IDBKeyRange.bound(lower, upper, false, false);

    var request = index.openCursor(boundKeyRange);
    request.onsuccess = function() {
        var cursor = request.result;
        if (cursor) {
            data.push(cursor.value);
            cursor.continue();
        } else {
            fun(data);
        }
    };
}
```

Можно, конечно, потом отсортировать массив объектов, как мне надо, но нельзя ли сразу взять и сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как всегда, немного почитав информации, форумов, статей о *indexedbd*, оказалось все весьма интересно. Как и написано в документации, выбрать можно только от меньшего к большему, но мы можем в *openCursor* инвертировать выдачу, т.е. вывести данные не слева направо, а наоборот, соответственно мы и получим записи с объектами, у которых выбранное нами поле равно от 2 -> 0, а не стандартное от 0 -> 2. Для того чтобы получить записи от большего к меньшему, меняем следующею строчку так:

```
var request = index.openCursor(boundKeyRange, 'prev');
```

Чтобы было совсем понятно, для примера возьмем такой массив объектов:

```
const customerData = [
  { id: 444, name: "Bill", age: 35, email: "bill@company.com" },
  { id: 5555, name: "Donna", age: 32, email: "donna@home.org" },
  { id: 666, name: "Cat", age: 2, email: "cat@home.org" },
  { id: 888, name: "Gandalf", age: 21000, email: "gandalf@home.org" }
];
```

Будем выбирать их из БД по полю **age**, мы хотим вывести объекты в порядке убывания, а не возрастания.

**openCursor(boundKeyRange), в порядке возрастания**:

```
Cat,Donna, Bill, Gandalf.
```

**openCursor(boundKeyRange, 'prev'), в порядке убывания**:

```
Gandalf, Bill, Donna, Cat
```